# Why does setting transition animation for FragmentTransactions cause Graphics memory to increase?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a setting Activity,it has many tabs;
when I call

```java
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .replace(identifier, Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentName, bundle))
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

to switch the tabs,

The graphics memory usage increased from 25MB to more than 80MB megabytes
[use transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6iiy.png)

but when I remove the `setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)`
and switch the tabs
[remove transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkwH3.png)

The graphics memory usage is always only 19MB.

I want to keep the transition effect, how can I optimize it?